# Declaring foreign key in Apache Derby database

Tags: database, derby

I am using Apache Derby database with ***ij*** 10.10.

I have two tables. First is `usertable` and the second is `logintable`.
In my `usertable` I have two columns: `userid` and `name`.
My `logintable` table has two columns: `userid` and `password`.
I need to set one column in `logintable` as foreign key where the primary key is in the `usertable`.

I used the following command to create the table:

```sql
create table usertable (userid varchar(10) primary key, name varchar(20));
```

How do I write the `logintable` to set the `userid` as a foreign key referring to the above primary key?

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you're looking for the FOREIGN KEY constraint syntax: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/rrefsqlj13590.html

And, more specifically, the REFERENCES syntax: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/rrefsqlj16357.html#rrefsqlj16357

So when you are creating the "logintable", at some point  in the CREATE TABLE statement you will have something like:

```
 CONSTRAINT login_userid_ref FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES usertable(userid)
```

Note that the SQL language has various alternate syntax styles for declaring referential integrity constraints like these; for example you can use a simpler syntax that ends up being something like:

```
create table logintable(
    userid varchar(10) references usertable(userid),
    password varchar(20));
```

Comment: I used the following statment for creating the login table with foreign key 
`create table logintable(userid varchar(10) references usertable(userid),password varchar(20));`
And this worked. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @rainu - your table creation worked for me and I would recreate your comment as an answer

Comment: @rainu I edited your suggested syntax into the answer -- thanks!